# Why does adding try! to writeln! stop an unused-code compiler warning?

Tags: rust

I'm following along the [Rust by Example Docs](http://rustbyexample.com/primitives/tuples.html),
and I got a compiler warning that I don't understand.

Consider this code:

```
use std::fmt::{self, Display};

struct Matrix(f32, f32, f32, f32);

impl Display for Matrix  {
    fn fmt(&self, f : &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        try!(writeln!(f, " ( {:.2}, {:.2} ) ", self.0, self.1));
        write!(f, " ( {:.2}, {:.2} ) ", self.2, self.3)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let m = Matrix(1f32,2f32,3f32,4f32); 
    print!("{}", m);
}
```

This compiles without error and works fine, but if we remove the `try!` from the first `writeln!`, so that the line becomes

```
writeln!(f, " ( {:.2}, {:.2} ) ", self.0, self.1);
```

I get this compiler warning:

```
<std macros>:2:1: 2:54 warning: unused result which must be used, #[warn(unused_must_use)] on by default
<std macros>:2 $ dst . write_fmt ( format_args ! ( $ ( $ arg ) * ) ) )
```

Why is that? What is the compiler trying to tell me? Does `writeln!` return some sort of error object that the `try!` is checking?

I found the source for the `writeln!` macro here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/36d746718086dfcc12f73562b1996daf2f8ba643/src/libcore/macros.rs#L396
but I don't yet understand it well enough yet to answer my own question.

rustc --version gives me `rustc 1.10.0 (cfcb716cf 2016-07-03)`, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`write!` and `writeln!` call a method named `write_fmt` on the first argument passed to the macro. This usually corresponds to the method from the [`std::io::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_fmt) or the [`std::fmt::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Write.html#method.write_fmt) trait (which require that you `use` the trait first), or from the [`std::fmt::Formatter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.write_fmt) struct.

You'll notice that they all return a [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html). `Result` has the `#[must_use]` attribute, which is what triggers the "unused result which must be used" warning.

`print!` and `println!`, on the other hand, just return `()`.

Comment: So the warning is telling me that I'm ignoring the return value from `writeln!`, and the `try!` makes the warning go away, because `try!` will look at `writeln!`'s return value to check whether the Result was successful?

Comment: That's correct. `try!` will cause the function to `return` if the result is an `Err`.